# Querying complex object wiht lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have school collection and schools have teacher collection and each teacher has student collection. Each student has global studentUniqueId.

I would like to find the school which has a student where studentUniqueId is : "Abc123946" by using lodash. It is possible to do it within loop but I would like to do it elegantly like we do in linq.

Sample data is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/94f4wvb6/

```
[  
   {  
  "schoolId":1,
  "schoolName":"school name 1",
  "teachers":[  
     {  
        "name":"Teacher Name 1",
        "subject":"Math",
        "students":[  
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123940",
              "name":"Student Name 1"
           },
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123941",
              "name":"Student Name 1"
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"Teacher Name 2",
        "subject":"English",
        "students":[  
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123942",
              "name":"Student Name 1"
           },
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123943",
              "name":"Student Name 1"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
},
{  
 "schoolId":2,
  "schoolName":"school name 2",
  "teachers":[  
     {  
        "name":"Teacher Name 3",
        "subject":"Math",
        "students":[  
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123944",
              "name":"Student Name 7"
           },
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123945",
              "name":"Student Name 8"
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "name":"Teacher Name 4",
        "subject":"English",
        "students":[  
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123946",
              "name":"Student Name 5"
           },
           {  
              "studentUniqueId":"Abc123947",
              "name":"Student Name 6"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it using [**find**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#find) and [**some**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#some):

```
let theOneThatIWant = "Abc123942";

let school = _.find(schools, function(school){
    return _.some(school.teachers, function(teacher){
        return _.some(teacher.students, {studentUniqueId: theOneThatIWant});
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_.find(schools, function(school) {
   return _.chain(school.teachers)
       .map('students')
       .flatten()
       .map('studentUniqueId')
       .includes('Abc123946')
       .value();
})
```

Comment: Looks elegant but, it says chain is not a function. Might it be it exists on  one of the previous version of lodash?